# insmod: page allocation failure

Tags: kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to this [experiment](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf) which is aimed at measuring code execution times on generic Linux. However, after I `insmod` and `dmesg`, I see `insmod: page allocation failure` and `unable to allocate memory for times [25]`. Can anyone give me some idea? What's wrong this code? It seem that it gets into trouble when it tries to malloc.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/hardirq.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define SIZE_OF_STAT 100000
#define BOUND_OF_LOOP 1000
#define UINT64_MAX (18446744073709551615ULL)

void inline measured_function(volatile int *var)
{
    (*var) = 1;
}

void inline Filltimes(uint64_t **times) {
    unsigned long flags;
    int i, j;
    uint64_t start, end;
    unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high, cycles_low1, cycles_high1;
    volatile int variable = 0;

    asm volatile ("CPUID\n\t"
                "RDTSC\n\t"
                "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile ("RDTSCP\n\t"
                "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile ("CPUID\n\t"
                "RDTSC\n\t"
                "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    asm volatile ("RDTSCP\n\t"
                "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
                "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");


    for (j=0; j<BOUND_OF_LOOP; j++) {
        for (i =0; i<SIZE_OF_STAT; i++) { 

            variable = 0;

            preempt_disable();
            raw_local_irq_save(flags);

            asm volatile (
                        "CPUID\n\t"
                        "RDTSC\n\t"
                        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
        /*call the function to measure here*/
            measured_function(&variable);

            asm volatile(
                        "RDTSCP\n\t"
                        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
                        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
                        "CPUID\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");

            raw_local_irq_restore(flags);
            preempt_enable();


            start = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low );

            end = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1 );

            if ( (end - start) < 0) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  CRITICAL ERROR IN TAKING THE TIME!!!!!!\n loop(%d) stat(%d) start = %llu, end = %llu, variable = %u\n", j, i, start, end, variable);
                times[j][i] = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                times[j][i] = end - start;
            }
        }
    }   
    return;
}
uint64_t var_calc(uint64_t *inputs, int size)
{
    int i;
    uint64_t acc = 0, previous = 0, temp_var = 0;
    for (i=0; i< size; i++) {
        if (acc < previous) goto overflow;
        previous = acc;
        acc += inputs[i];
    }
    acc = acc * acc;
    if (acc < previous) goto overflow;
    previous = 0;
    for (i=0; i< size; i++){
        if (temp_var < previous) goto overflow;
        previous = temp_var;
        temp_var+= (inputs[i]*inputs[i]);
    }
    temp_var = temp_var * size;
    if (temp_var < previous) goto overflow;
    temp_var =(temp_var - acc)/(((uint64_t)(size))*((uint64_t)(size)));
    return (temp_var);
overflow:
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>> CRITICAL OVERFLOW ERROR IN var_calc!!!!!!\n\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, spurious = 0, k =0;
    uint64_t **times;
    uint64_t *variances;
    uint64_t *min_values;
    uint64_t max_dev = 0, min_time = 0, max_time = 0, prev_min =0, tot_var=0, max_dev_all=0, var_of_vars=0, var_of_mins=0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");

    times = kmalloc(BOUND_OF_LOOP*sizeof(uint64_t*), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!times) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "unable to allocate memory for times\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (j=0; j<BOUND_OF_LOOP; j++) {
        times[j] = kmalloc(SIZE_OF_STAT*sizeof(uint64_t), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!times[j]) {
            printk(KERN_ERR "unable to allocate memory for times[%d]\n", j);
            for (k=0; k<j; k++)
                kfree(times[k]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    variances = kmalloc(BOUND_OF_LOOP*sizeof(uint64_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!variances) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "unable to allocate memory for variances\n");
        return 0;
    }

    min_values = kmalloc(BOUND_OF_LOOP*sizeof(uint64_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!min_values) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "unable to allocate memory for min_values\n");
        return 0;
    }


    Filltimes(times);

    for (j=0; j<BOUND_OF_LOOP; j++) {

        max_dev = 0;
        min_time = 0;
        max_time = 0;

        for (i =0; i<SIZE_OF_STAT; i++) {
            if ((min_time == 0)||(min_time > times[j][i]))
                min_time = times[j][i];
            if (max_time < times[j][i])
            max_time = times[j][i];
        }

        max_dev = max_time - min_time;
        min_values[j] = min_time;

        if ((prev_min != 0) && (prev_min > min_time))
            spurious++;
        if (max_dev > max_dev_all)
            max_dev_all = max_dev;

        variances[j] = var_calc(times[j], SIZE_OF_STAT);
        tot_var += variances[j];

        printk(KERN_ERR "loop_size:%d >>>> variance(cycles): %llu; max_deviation: %llu ;min time: %llu", j, variances[j], max_dev, min_time);

        prev_min = min_time;
    }

    var_of_vars = var_calc(variances, BOUND_OF_LOOP);
    var_of_mins = var_calc(min_values, BOUND_OF_LOOP);
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n total number of spurious min values = %d", spurious);
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n total variance = %llu", (tot_var/BOUND_OF_LOOP));
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n absolute max deviation = %llu", max_dev_all);
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n variance of variances = %llu", var_of_vars);
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n variance of minimum values = %llu", var_of_mins);

    for (j=0; j<BOUND_OF_LOOP; j++) {
        kfree(times[j]);
    }
    kfree(times);
    kfree(variances);
    kfree(min_values);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Comment: Memory allocation can fail in case of insufficient memory or defragmentation.

Comment: All timing code affects the performance, but I think you can reduce the impact of yours.  Looking at your first asm, it requires gcc free 6 registers for use (abcd + 2), when you really only need 4, and takes 4 instructions when you only need 2.  Also, doesn't the operation (and thus perhaps the timing) of `cpuid` vary depending on the value of eax (which you do not explicitly set)?  How about `asm volatile ("CPUID\n\t" "RDTSC\n\t" : "=d" (cycles_high), "=a" (cycles_low): "a" (0) : "%rbx", "%rcx");`.  Your other asm statements can be modified similarly.  Doesn't solve your problem, but still.